# using Facebook Graph to POST an Image with object_attachment => Graph Error response

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-5.3

I have code that retrieves everything I need (to include user id tags) yet from var umping my responses, I see that my `object_attachment` is creating this error.

My code:

```
 public function newPost(UserModel $user){

        $this->fb->setDefaultAccessToken($user->accounts->where("network","facebook")->first()->access_token);

         $message = 'Look at this amazing photo';
         $photoUrl = 'http://weneedfun.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Amazing-Pictures-4.jpg';

         $photoRequester = $this->fb->request('POST', 'me/photos', ['url' => $photoUrl, 'published' => 'false']);
         $photoResponseBodyId = $this->requestResponse($photoRequester)->getDecodedBody()['id'];

         $friendsTagged = ['25235235', '52525222'];


        $request = $this->fb->request('POST','me/feed', ["message" => $message, "tags"=> $friendsTagged, "object_attachment" => $photoResponseBodyId]);
         $responseBody = $this->requestResponse($request)->getDecodedBody();

        var_dump($request);
        var_dump($responseBody);
         die();
         /*return $responseBody;*/
    }
```

When I remove the above request and leave it as:

```
$request = $this->fb->request('POST','me/feed', ["message" => $message, "tags"=> $friendsTagged]);
```

it works just fine.

what am I doing wrong fellow stackers?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, don't ask me why but FB wants all returning values in an array (even if there's 1 image.)

Here's the request working:

```
 $request = $this->fb->request('POST','me/feed', [
            'message' => $message,
            'tags' => $friendsTagged,
            'attached_media[0]' => '{"media_fbid":"'.$photoResponseBodyId.'"}'
        ]);
```